# Editable Text Fields - Pass Data Backwards Between View Controllers (with Navigation Controller)

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am making an app where I want a user to be able to create a new "walk set" (basically a flash card set), then return back to the opening screen, and be able to tap on any of their sets, taking them to a screen where they can edit them.

The problem is that I don't know how to save the edits of the terms in the set AKA pass data from the editing VC back to the opening VC. A regular prepare-for-segue isn't working because every time I try to make a segue from the editing VC back to the opening VC it messes the whole thing up because of the Navigation Controller. So I think I want to still transition with just a "self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)", and yet still pass data.

**Code from OpeningScreenViewController (the initial screen with the table of walk sets shown):**

```
class OpeningScreenViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextViewDelegate {  
    
    @IBOutlet var table: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!

    var models: [(name: String, term1: String, term2: String, term3: String)] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        table.delegate = self
        table.dataSource = self
        title = "Walks"  
    }
    
    @IBAction func didTapNewWalk(){
        guard let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "new") as? NewWalkViewController else {
            return
        }
        vc.title = "New Walk"
        vc.completion = { theName, theTerm1, theTerm2, theTerm3 in
            self.models.append((name: theName, term1: theTerm1, term2: theTerm2, term3: theTerm3))
            self.label.isHidden = true
            self.table.isHidden = false
            
            self.table.reloadData()
        }
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
    
    //Table stuff
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return models.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = models[indexPath.row].name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = models[indexPath.row].term1
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        
        var model = models[indexPath.row]
  
        //show walk controller
        
        guard let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "edit") as? EditExistingWalkController else {
                return
        }
        
        //passes data to EditExistingWalkController for the first time
        vc.title = "Edit Walk"
        vc.addTapCountAgain = model.addCount
        vc.nameAgain = model.name
        vc.term1TextAgain = model.term1
        vc.term2TextAgain = model.term2
        vc.term3TextAgain = model.term3
        
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

**Code from NewWalkViewController (the screen when a user taps the "+" button in OpeningScreenViewController):**

```
class NewWalkViewController: UIViewController {

    //saves term data
    public var completion: ((String, String, String, String) -> Void)?

    @IBOutlet weak var nameOfWalkSet: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var term1TxtField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var term2TxtField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var term3TxtField: UITextField!
    
    @IBAction func saveButn(_ sender: Any) {
        if let text = term1TxtField.text, !text.isEmpty, let text2 = nameOfWalkSet.text, !text2.isEmpty {
        completion?(text2, text, term2TxtField.text ?? "", term3TxtField.text ?? "")
        
            //goes back to opening screen
            self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
        }
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()  
    }
}
extension NewWalkViewController : UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
}
```

**Code from EditExistingWalkController (the screen after a user had made a walk set and taps on a cell in the table in OpeningScreenViewController):**

```
class EditExistingWalkController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
        
    //these are the text fields that I'm ultimately trying to save and pass the strings that the entered in them
    @IBOutlet weak var nameOfWalkSetEdit: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var term1TxtFieldEdit: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var term2TxtFieldEdit: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var term3TxtFieldEdit: UITextField!
    
    //setting it up so that receives data from model thing in Opening Screen VC
    public var addTapCountAgain: Int = 1
    public var nameAgain: String = "" 
    public var term1TextAgain: String = ""
    public var term2TextAgain: String = ""
    public var term3TextAgain: String = ""
    
    @IBAction func saveButnEdit(_ sender: Any) {
        if let text = term1TxtFieldEdit?.text, !text.isEmpty, let text2 = nameOfWalkSetEdit?.text, !text2.isEmpty {

            //THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO PASS DATA BEFORE SWITCHING VCs

            self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
         }
        
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        //loads text from Opening to go in the textfield boxes in the EditExistingWalk screen
        nameOfWalkSetEdit?.text = nameAgain
        term1TxtFieldEdit?.text = term1TextAgain
        term2TxtFieldEdit?.text = term2TextAgain
        term3TxtFieldEdit?.text = term3TextAgain 
    }
}
```

[Storyboard screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36PBA.png)

Comment: `if let vc = self.navigationController?.viewControllers[0] as? OpeningScreenViewController { /* pass data to vc */ }`

Comment: Thank you @matt - savior!! One question: how would I update the label on the cell (in the tableView function in OpeningSceneViewController)?

Comment: OpeningSceneViewController needs to have a method that permits that. Plan ahead for what info you'll need to receive.